# I have a basic problem understanding CSS positioning

Tags: html, css

Edit: Ok, this is what works. It may not be "right", but 1) it displays correctly & 2) it validates at W3C.  It seems that I should make all positioning absoolute and add positioning to all divs except for those with a fieldset, where I have to add the position to the fieldset. Feel free to correct this if you think that I am wrong, but "it works for me" ! Yay! Yipee! At last! Lots of +1 all round and thanks to all who helped.

---

Edit: the bounty goes to whomever can post the editted HTML which displays like the Delphi screenshot.

---

I am using Borland Delphi to produce an HTML form generator. The user can drag & drop components to produce a file and when he is happy he can generate HTML (I pop a Submit button on to the end of his form).

Since I have the absolute position of each control when I am generating, I want so specify absolute positions in CSS. I thought this meant that I have to use `position: fixed`, but that doesn't look right, and nor does absolute.

What am I doing wrong? (the HTML validates at W3C)

Here is a very basic basic example as seen when designing the form in the Delphi program
[image]

And here it is in MSIE 8 (with fix position)
[image]

And again with absolute position
[image]

And, finally, here is the HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Input data</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
<form action="http://localhost/a_submitted.php" method="post">
<div class="TGroupBox" id="GroupBox1">
<fieldset style="position: absolute; top:40px; left:40px; width: 857px; height: 441px;">
<legend>GroupBox1</legend>
<div class="TPanel" id="Panel1">
<fieldset style="position: absolute; top:64px; left:56px; width: 753px; height: 369px;">
<legend></legend>
<div class="TLabel" id="Label1" style="position: absolute; top:88px; left: 80px; width: 32px; height: 13px;">Label1</div>
<div class="TEdit" id="Edit1" style="position: absolute; top:80px; left: 72px; width: 121px; height: 21px;"><input type="text" name="Edit1" value="an edit bx"></div>
<div class="TCheckBox" id="CheckBox1" style="position: absolute; top:88px; left: 80px; width: 97px; height: 17px;">CheckBox1<input type="checkbox" name="CheckBox1" value="CheckBox1Checked"></div>
<div class="TComboBox" id="ComboBox1" style="position: absolute; top:145px; left: 137px; width: 145px; height: 21px;">
  <select size ="1" name="ComboBox1">
    <option value="one" selected="selected">one    </option>
    <option value="two">two    </option>
    <option value="three">three    </option>
</select>
</div>
<div class="TRadioGroup" id="RadioGroup1">
<fieldset style="position: absolute; top:144px; left: 136px; width: 185px; height: 105px;"><legend>RadioGroup1</legend>
      red: <input type="radio" name="RadioGroup1" value=""><br>
      white: <input type="radio" name="RadioGroup1" value="" checked><br>
      blue: <input type="radio" name="RadioGroup1" value=""><br>
</fieldset>
</div>
</fieldset>
</div>
</fieldset>
</div>
<div><input type="submit" name="submitButton" value="Submit" style="position:relative; top:25px; left: 50%;"></div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

---

Edit: the bounty goes to whomever can post the editted HTML which displays like the Delphi screenshot.

---

Edit: Ok, this is what works. It may not be "right", but 1) it displays correctly & 2) it validates at W3C.  It seems that I should make all positioning absoolute and add positioning to all divs except for those with a fieldset, where I have to add the position to the fieldset. Feel free to correct this if you think that I am wrong, but "it works for me" ! Yay! Yipee! At last! Lots of +1 all round and thanks to all who helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start with the following code. Make sure you read what others have posted:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Input data</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
<form action="http://localhost/a_submitted.php" method="post">
    <div class="TGroupBox" id="GroupBox1">
        <fieldset style="">
            <legend>GroupBox1</legend>
            <div class="TPanel" id="Panel1">
                <fieldset style="width: 600px; height: 250px; margin: 20px 50px 50px 20px; padding: 20px; padding-left: 50px">
                    <div class="TLabel" id="Label1" style="position: absolute; left: 100px; top: 100px;">Label1</div>
                    <div class="TEdit" id="Edit1" style="position: absolute; left: 200px; top: 100px;"><input type="text" name="Edit1" value="an edit bx"></div>
                    <div class="TCheckBox" id="CheckBox1" style="position: absolute; left: 400px; top: 100px;">CheckBox1 <input type="checkbox" name="CheckBox1" value="CheckBox1Checked"></div>
                    <div class="TComboBox" id="ComboBox1" style="position: absolute; left: 100px; top: 150px;">
                        <select size ="1" name="ComboBox1" style="width: 200px;">
                            <option value="one" selected="selected">one</option>
                            <option value="two">two</option>
                            <option value="three">three</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="TRadioGroup" id="RadioGroup1" style="position: absolute; left: 380px; top: 150px;">
                        <fieldset style="">
                            <legend>RadioGroup1</legend>
                                <input type="radio" name="RadioGroup1" value=""> red<br>
                                <input type="radio" name="RadioGroup1" value="" checked> white<br>
                                <input type="radio" name="RadioGroup1" value=""> blue<br>
                        </fieldset>
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
    <div><input type="submit" name="submitButton" value="Submit" style=""></div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That looks like the answer - except that groupbox1 is as wide as the browser. If you add the pistion to that then you have the answer.  I will couple that with what otehrs ahve said (and award many more +1 if there is anywhere that I have not yet done so).  What was my problem? Not subtracting parent.top & parent.left from top & left?

Comment: You need to start with plain HTML and add CSS properties once you have the main layout on screen. Of course it helps to have an understanding of how CSS works, especially positioning. What you shouldn't do is to start putting values here and there. Work with one element at a time and progress slowly. Finally, studying other peoples' work help tremendously.

Comment: +1 Thanks! I tried that - one at a time, slowly, one at a time, and it goes well until I nest components. Btw, I tried asking a related question at  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3226799/html-forms-css-should-position-be-on-the-enclosing-div-or-the-enclosed-cont  and they say that the position goes on the DIV and not on the <fieldset>. Any comment?

Comment: Look, @Anax, this works, but I have two small problems: 1) you didn't put any position on the outermost GroupBox1 and it fills the width of the screen, and 2) I still don't understand the how & why of it.  I'll try to worjk it out

Comment: Btw, I would prefer to just specify top/left/width/height and not specify margin & padding - can I do that?

Comment: You need to view `DIV` as placeholder, whereas a `FIELDSET` is an element which allows you to group related controls and labels. If you want to duplicate the exact look of a form you will most probably have to alter the `style` property of all elements. Regarding the outermost GroupBox1, you need to fill in the style of the `FIELDSET` element to which it belongs. For example you could add some padding or some margin. Finally, why do you insist on specifying top/left/width/height instead of margin/padding? Use whichever will take you to your goal more easily.

Comment: Thanks, @Anax (+1)   Ok, so positioning on DIV, only on the controls (like fieldset, input type, etc)?      I use left/top for positioning and width/height rather than margin/padding because that what delphi has, so it woudl seem to make it easier to use those...

Answer (score 8):

`position: fixed` means `top:`, `right:`, `bottom:`, and `left:` are relative to the browser window and the element doesn't scroll with the page.

`position: relative` means `top:`, `right:`, `bottom:`, and `left:` are relative to where the top, right, bottom, and left sides of the element *would have been* if there was no positioning. It *also* means any absolutely positioned child elements are placed relative to this element.

`position: absolute` means `top:`, `right:`, `bottom:`, and `left:` are relative to the sides of the nearest relatively positioned element that contains it. If it's not inside a relatively positioned element, `position: absolute` works the way most people expect at first: `top:`, `right:`, `bottom:`, and `left:` are relative to the edges of the page.

---

For what it looks like you're trying to do, I think you should position each element like this

```
<div style="position: absolute; left: {X}px; top: {Y}px">
```

where {X} and {Y} are replaced with the coordinates of the top left corner of the element as it appears in the form designer.

Comment: +1 Ah, so the position should be on the div and not on the component which it encloses? Or, if fact, maybe it should be on both?   (and I'd like to give height/width as well as top/left, if that's ok.

Comment: Hmmm, "An absolute position element is positioned relative to the first parent element that has a position other than static" ... so in my delphi code, maybe I should make everything CSS absolute, but since Delphi components are really absolute, with respect to the screen, then instead of writing the positions as copment.top, component. left, I should write them as copment.top - compnent.parent.top, component.parent.left etc?

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that absolute positioning is relative to the parent with absolute positioning. If the parent isn't absolutly position it will look up the tree utill it find absolutly positioned element or the body.
Simply: make sure everything is absolutly positioned including The form and the divs.

Comment: +1, so I position bothe the divs and the componets which they enclose? But does that include a fraemset?

Answer (score 1):

To help your understanding about CSS positioning: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

Comment: That's what I think I am doing with fixed-position. Any idea why it is not working?

Comment: Try to change `left` to `margin-left` and `top` to `margin-top` for `absolute` position, and see the difference.

Comment: Sorry, jeaffrey, that did not help

Comment: `margin` refers to the space around an element. It's part of the "box model," along with `border` and `padding`. It's not related to positioning.

Answer (score 1):

I actually just ran into this problem. If a div is absolutely positioned and nested inside another div that is not absolutely positioned, it will be positioned relative to the parent div.

In your code, for example, `Label1` is absolutely positioned, but it is inside `Panel1`, which is not absolutely positioned.

You can either make all levels of your div tree absolutely positioned, or you can use negative values to position things where you want them. Both can get messy if you aren't careful.

Comment: +1 Thanks. I thought I was making it easy by absolutely positioning everything, but I thought I just had to positoin the components - didn't realize I needed to position the divs too.   On Groupbox1 to I need to position teh fieldset as well as the div?

Answer (score 1):

I'd say the problem is in the values for `top` and `left` you're giving to the nested absolutely positioned elements.

For an absolutely positioned parent and child, the child's coordinates are relative to the parent. You can check this fact [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Jsfzr/). Play with the values and see for yourself.

Another problem with your code, is that for form elements you shouldn't be setting the width/height on the containing elements. You should set it on the form element itself.

Edit: I tried to calculate the proper values, It's not perfect as i don't have the values from the delphi program and the values you're using are not the values given by the delphi program as evident from your code and screenshots. See the result [here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/2Cymv/).

Comment: +1 but I was hoping that some CSS guru would give me the acutal answer as I am lost here

Answer (score 1):

Just setting the `position` to absolute is not enough, basically to fix the position you just have to play with `left` and `top` styles of the elements.

Here is the fixed HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <title>Input data</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
<form action="http://localhost/a_submitted.php" method="post">
<div class="TGroupBox" id="GroupBox1">
<fieldset style="position: absolute; top:40px; left:40px; width: 857px; height: 441px;">
<legend>GroupBox1</legend>
<div class="TPanel" id="Panel1">
<fieldset style="position: absolute; top:10px; left:10px; width: 753px; height: 369px;">
<div class="TLabel" id="Label1" style="position: absolute; top:35px; left: 80px; width: 32px; height: 13px;">Label1</div>
<div class="TEdit" id="Edit1" style="position: absolute; top:35px; left: 200px; width: 121px; height: 21px;"><input type="text" name="Edit1" value="an edit bx"></div>
<div class="TCheckBox" id="CheckBox1" style="position: absolute; top:35px; left: 420px; width: 97px; height: 17px;"><input type="checkbox" name="CheckBox1" value="CheckBox1Checked"> CheckBox1</div>
<div class="TComboBox" id="ComboBox1" style="position: absolute; top:145px; left: 80px; width: 145px; height: 21px;">
<select size ="1" name="ComboBox1">
<option value="one" selected="selected">one    </option>
<option value="two">two    </option>
<option value="three">three    </option>
</select>
</div>
<div class="TRadioGroup" id="RadioGroup1">
<fieldset style="position: absolute; top:145px; left: 250px; width: 185px; height: 105px;"><legend>RadioGroup1</legend>
red: <input type="radio" name="RadioGroup1" value=""><br>
white: <input type="radio" name="RadioGroup1" value="" checked><br>
blue: <input type="radio" name="RadioGroup1" value=""><br>
</fieldset>
</div>
</fieldset>
</div>
</fieldset>
</div>
<div><input type="submit" name="submitButton" value="Submit" style="position:relative; top:28px; left: 50%;"></div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

your problem is simply that IE is a ridiculous and unstable browser. It rarely displays pages correctly and usually has problems with pages that work in every other browser. Try using chrome, safari, opera, or firefox instead.

Comment: +1 because I tend to agree with you, but I have no choice - I have to use MS IE

Comment: "and usually has problems with pages that work in every other browser" = hyperbole