# HTML forms / CSS - should "position" be on the enclosing DIV or the enclosed control?

Tags: css, styling

Which is correct?

```
<div class="TEdit" id="Edit1" style="position: absolute; left: 200px; top: 100px;">
    <input type="text" name="Edit1" value="an edit bx">
</div>
```

or

```
<div class="TEdit" id="Edit1" >
    <input type="text" style="position: absolute; left: 200px; top: 100px;" name="Edit1" value="an edit bx">
</div>
```

see also related question [I have a basic problem understanding CSS positioning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3183297/i-have-a-basic-problem-understanding-css-positioning/3225332#3225332)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First one is correct because div is parent tag:

```
<div class="TEdit" id="Edit1" style="position: absolute; left: 200px; top:  
 100px;"><input type="text" name="Edit1" value="an edit bx"></div>
```

Comment: +1 (and probably the answer) Thanks. So, I position the DIVs and for any <fieldset> used as containers I can use "position=absolute" but have to use top & left *relative* to the containing <fieldset>, right?

Answer (score 1):

**First one is correct.**

Position should given to the DIV not onlt because it is a parent tag but also it's a content tag.